# What future applications could nanoarchitecture be used for?

Tags: internal-consistency, nanotechnology

I was reading about nano-architecture, but it didn't really say what it could be used for in the future. They mentioned something about 3-D printing but that's it. I'm toying with using it in my future world.

Comment: Please specify your problem and you will likely get an answer. This is not a place for "give me ideas".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even 3-D printing itself covers pretty much everything (...that can be printed).
Possible applications are:

- Composing ultra-light materials with an outstanding durability (aircraft, spacecraft, etc)
- Nanobots or complicated medicine containers to travel inside human body
- Nano-art. Why not?
- Creating weird materials with unusual physical characteristics. For example, buildings with 'soft' walls so that they can withstand an earthquake.
- I've also read something about creating long-life batteries with this technology, let's count this one too.

These are the first things that come to mind.